# d3.js dirty svg (empty tag) after filtering

Tags: svg, d3.js, filter

I discover D3.js and I try to filter data (just after an .append). It works visually but if i check the generated SVG, empty tag are generated too.

Simple illustration :

```
    var data = d3.range(10);
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");

    var shapes = svg.selectAll(".shapes")
        .data(data).enter();

    shapes.append("circle")
        .filter(function(d){ return d < 5; })
        .attr("cx", function(d, i){ return (i+1) * 25; })
        .attr("cy", 10)
        .attr("r", 10);
```

render :

```
<svg>
<circle cx="25" cy="10" r="10"/>
<circle cx="50" cy="10" r="10"/>
<circle cx="75" cy="10" r="10"/>
<circle cx="100" cy="10" r="10"/>
<circle cx="125" cy="10" r="10"/>
<circle/>
<circle/>
<circle/>
<circle/>
<circle/>
</svg>
```

Why the 5 circles exclude by the filter appear as empty tags? 
Is there a way to obtain a "clean" svg after using a filter method?
Or, how to filter data and obtain a clean svg by another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter on the data join, like this:

```
var shapes = svg.selectAll(".shapes")
        .data(data.filter(function(d){ return d < 5; })).enter();

shapes.append("circle")
        .attr("cx", function(d, i){ return (i+1) * 25; })
        .attr("cy", 10)
        .attr("r", 10);
```

(assuming you don't need the data for any other objects - obviously depends on the task at hand).